# Invariant framing of $S^1$ and "the other one"

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

It is known that the left invariant framing of $S^1$ generates $\Omega_1^{fr}$ (the stably framed bordism group of 1-dimensional manifolds). I do not understand how "the other" framing looks like which gives the zero element in $\Omega_1^{fr}$. Can someone explain this to me?

(First I thought it would be the framing obtained by reversing orientation, but this should give the same element in $\Omega_1^{fr}$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-stably the zero element is easy to see i think. just imagine a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an outward (or inward) pointing normal. You can see by hand that this is framed cobordant to the empty set. But now you can just suspend: Take the same circle with this framing and see it sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ with a constant basis of the normal space in the other two directions. Thus the framing of the standard circle $\{(x,y,0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^4\,x^2+y^2=1\}$ at the point $(x,y,0,0)$ is $e_1=(x,y,0,0),e_2=(0,0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,0,1)$.

The non-zero element in framed cobordism can be seen as follows: take a non-zero contractible loop $S^1\rightarrow SO(3)$ and let it act on the basis above pointwise.

EDIT: Consider the circle $S^1\subset \mathbb R^2$ with the outward pointing normal as a framing. Consider the $W=\{(x,y,z)\subset \mathbb R^2\times [0,1]\,|\,x^2+y^2+2z^2=1.\}$ with framing $(x,y,2z)$. This is a framed nullbordism. I encourage you to make a drawing. You can even go one dimension lower: Take $S^0\subset \mathbb R$ (two points) with outward normal. This extends over an arc $\gamma\subset \mathbb R\times[0,1]$ with boundary on $S^0\times\{0\}$.

Comment: I dont see that the standard normal framing of  $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ is framed cobordant to the empty set. This would mean, that this framing can be extended to the unit disk, which is clearly not possibly, since this is the identity map on $S^1$.

Comment: The framing needs to be extended to a disc $D^2\subset \mathbb R^3$. Does that help? Or you can consider the map $S^2\rightarrow S^1$ by $(x,y,z)\mapsto (z,\sqrt(1-z^2))$. The framed submanifold that one obtains from a regular value is the one I describe in my answer. But the map is contractible, hence the framed submanifold is framed nullbordant.

Comment: Sorry, I still have problems to understand. This framing is the identity map on $S^1$. So there is no extension to any disk, right?

Comment: @WilhelmL.: Does this edit help?

Comment: The map is the identify map as seen as a map $S^1\rightarrow S^1$. But the framing is a map $S^1$ to the normal bundle of $S^1$. This is trivial.

Comment: Maybe you mean $x^2+y^2\mathbf{-}2z^2=0$ in your edit?

Comment: Thanks, it should be equal to one